# Node app crashes after a while on micro EC2 instance even with supervisor

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, node.js, debugging, supervisord

I'm using [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to start my node.js application on a micro EC2 instance. However, the app only stays running for some time until it eventually shuts down. Not exactly sure how long the app stays running but I'm guessing for about a few hours or so. Sometimes less. My question is where on the remote server should I be looking in order to debug this kind of issue? I'm running an Amazon Linux AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get node log using this supervisord configuration. After a crash, you will get what really happened. Provably the error might be because node crash for some unexpected  error. Try to use console.logs

```
 ; ------- NODE -------
 [program:node]
 command=/usr/local/bin/node app.js
 directory=/var/www/node
 environment=NODE_ENV=production
 user=root
 stdout_logfile=/var/log/node/node.log
 stderr_logfile=/var/log/node/node.error
 serverurl=AUTO
 ; ---- END NODE CONFIG ----
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the relevant information would show up in the stdout file or stderr file?

Comment: yes sure! I think you will have some route you're accessing or your code enters in infinite loop. Try it and edit your post with your stderr.

Comment: Actually I used the supervisor you suggested and the site now is staying up!

Comment: Great! But remember you still have a bug ;) you are just hiding it. Try to find where your scripts die.